# Excel VBA Error "Next Without For" Because Of Many IFs

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code and VBA is giving me a "Next Without For" Error when I definitely have both. I checked on the internet and understand that it is because of many ifs, can someone tell me where is my problem?

i have 3 workbboks and I want that each row will be cut and copied into the right workbook acording to the nimber in column I.

```
     Dim i As Integer
    Dim RowTable As Integer

RowTable = Sheets(3).Range("A1", (Range("A1").End(xlDown))).Rows.count


'loop


For i = 2 To RowTable

'SORTING DATA TO WORKBOOKS



'Oren, Karin, Noam

'Oren
If Selection.Value = 1 Then

Selection.EntireRow.Cut
WB1.Activate
WB1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select

        If Selection.Value = "" Then
        Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Else
        Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If


    Else

'Karin
If Selection.Value = 2 Then

Selection.EntireRow.Cut
WB1.Activate
WB1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select

        If Selection.Value = "" Then
        Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Else
        Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If


    Else

'Noam
If Selection.Value = 3 Then

Selection.EntireRow.Cut
WB1.Activate
WB1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select

        If Selection.Value = "" Then
        Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Else
        Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If




End If

'next row

  mainWB.Activate
  Sheets(3).Range("I2").End(xlDown).Select





'i do the same procedure in the indirect manager workbooks as i did in the first workbook
'i will copy the names to a differen range and then remove duplicates
'then i will have a list of direct managers in each wb
'and i will name ech direct manager as a number and open a worksheet based on his name


Next
```

Comment: Instead of too many `If`'s, consider that you don't have enough `End If`'s. Each multiline `If` statement needs to terminate with `End If`.  I count 6 `If`'s and only 4 `End If`'s

Comment: VBA will treat Next, Loop, End If, End With and End Select as one group when finding any of them missing. This frequently results in incorrect error messages, such as you have where the message says that the "Next" is missing whereas, in fact, it is an "End If".

Comment: I think you wanted to use `ElseIf` statements, rather than an `Else` statement followed by an inner `If` statement.  (And, FWIW, your code inside each of the legs of the outer `If` seems to be identical, so I'm not sure why you are using it.)

Comment: Why not indent your code logically? As illustrated by your question, failure to indent code properly, especially when the code involves nested control structures, is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: clean up the code formatting (it is horrendous), and you will probably see the problem

Answer (score 5):

VBA intends to help avoid such errors as you have by supporting indenting. The logic you should try to implement would look like this:-

```
For n = 1 to 10
    If 1 <> 2 Then
        'enter code here
    Else
        Do
            ' enter code here
        Loop While 0 <> 0
    End If
Next n
```

I have rearranged your code according to the above principle. This is the result.

```
Private Sub FormattedCode()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim RowTable As Integer

    RowTable = Sheets(3).Range("A1", (Range("A1").End(xlDown))).Rows.Count


    'loop


    For i = 2 To RowTable

        'SORTING DATA TO WORKBOOKS
        'Oren, Karin, Noam
        If Selection.Value = 1 Then             ' Oren

            Selection.EntireRow.Cut
            WB1.Activate
            WB1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select

            If Selection.Value = "" Then
                Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            End If                      ' this I inserted
        Else
            Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If
'            Else                       ' this is illegal here

        If Selection.Value = 2 Then             'Karin

            Selection.EntireRow.Cut
            WB1.Activate
            WB1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select

            If Selection.Value = "" Then
                Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            End If                      ' this I inserted
        Else
            Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If
'            Else                       ' this is illegal here

        If Selection.Value = 3 Then             ' Noam

            Selection.EntireRow.Cut
            WB1.Activate
            WB1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select

            If Selection.Value = "" Then
                Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            End If                      ' this I inserted
        Else
            Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If

'        End If                         ' superfluous

        'next row

        mainWB.Activate
        Sheets(3).Range("I2").End(xlDown).Select

        'i do the same procedure in the indirect manager workbooks as i did in the first workbook
        'i will copy the names to a differen range and then remove duplicates
        'then i will have a list of direct managers in each wb
        'and i will name ech direct manager as a number and open a worksheet based on his name

    Next
End Sub
```